# php curl work fine on localhost but no result on server

Tags: php, curl

I use php curl, it works fine on `localhost` but no result on server (after 60 sec trying)

```
$ch = curl_init ($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'x.x.x.x:808');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
echo $output = curl_exec ($ch);
```

Comment: Is your Proxy accessible from your Web Server? The proxy might only be configured for local requests.

Comment: @Twisty i don't know exactly, I installed a CCProxy in my vps for proxy accounting
how i can check it?

Comment: I am assuming your local environment is a test VM then? and the Server envonment is hosted external to your local environment? I would try commenting out `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'x.x.x.x:808');` and test on the Server.